# How to verify if a repository is already added

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have two repository that I want my script to verify if they are on the system. How can I verify by command line if a repository is already added to the system and, if not, add them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see all repository enabled in terminal with this command below (It will print all repository line starting with `deb` or `deb-src`)

```
find /etc/apt/ -name *.list | xargs cat | grep  ^[[:space:]]*deb
```

**Explanation:** first `find` find all files with `.list` extension in `/etc/apt` directory and feeds `xargs` the list, which in turn print all text on all of those files to the display device i.e Monitor. Then `grep` select those lines of which starts with `deb`. I have used extra step to include those lines also which starts with whitespace characters instead of `deb`.

If you want to see only the repositories with binary packages not source packages (deb-src), use another grep to exclude entries with `deb-src` like this one:

```
find /etc/apt/ -name *.list | xargs cat | grep  ^[[:space:]]*deb | grep -v deb-src
```

**To add the repository using command line,** just use this kind of command:

*(I am assuming your repository source line is like this `deb http://mydomain.com/ubuntu precise main` )*

```
echo deb http://mydomain.com/ubuntu precise main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This command uses `tee` program which is used to read and write from standard input to standard output. Here, it takes the echoed repo line and put that line at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file which is the main repository source file.

Please note that without using `-a` option for `tee` the entire `sources.list` will be replaced with the just echoed line.

Alternatively you can use your own file for the custom repo without touching `sources.list` file. For example,

```
echo deb http://mydomain.com/ubuntu precise main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teles.list
```

It will create a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory with name `teles.list` containing line `deb http://mydomain.com/ubuntu precise main`.

***Note that, to add repository source to the system your script need to be run with root priviledge***

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `grep`, if the repository name is in `REPO` variable, do something like this:

```
if ! grep -q "$REPO" /etc/apt/sources.list; then
  # do something if repo is not installed
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is what you need but typing

```
software-properties-gtk
```

in a terminal or in dash-command windows will open a list of software sources.

Use this command to add your PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:YOUR PPA HERE
```

Hope that helps

EDIT: You can edit the file with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` if that's needed. `nano` is a terminal text editor you may have to do this first

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

to install it.

Comment: Isn't there a command line that make the same that SPG do? Because I don't have how to access the Gtk window to read the list of repos xD

But thank you for your help!

Comment: Plese see my edit to open the sources list in a terminal

Comment: nano is installed by default in Ubuntu.